# Why aren't these overloads ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, ambiguous-call

The following code compiles fine with gcc and clang.

```
template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(typename identity<T>::type);

template <typename T>
void foo(T);

int main()
{
    foo<int>(0);
}
```

It looks like overload resolution is choosing the first overload (the `identity<T>::type` one).

Could someone explain why the overloads aren't ambiguous? As far as I can tell, the only difference between them is that the argument of the first one is a non-deduced context and the argument of the second one isn't, but since I'm providing the template argument explicitly, I don't see why that should matter.

Comment: Interesting. Obviously the second function would have been chosen if you had enabled type deduction by not explicitly instantiating `foo<int>(0)` but `foo(0)` instead (No type deduction for the identity meta function). @Andy Prowl: I dont want to question your answer put point out that your reasoning is not as obvious as it may appear. Give the foo parameter a default value and call `foo<int>()` without parameter. Your argumentation should still apply but now the overloads are indeed ambiguous as HighCommander4 expected. Explicit template instantiation of function templates is complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both overloads are viable, but the former is *more specialized* than the latter, and therefore it gets picked by overload resolution.

Per paragraph 13.3.3/1 of the C++11 Standard on overload resolution:

> [...] a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> — for some argument j, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`, or, if not that,
>
> — the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the
>   standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
>   entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
>   the return type of `F2` to the destination type. [ ... ] or, if not that,
>
> — `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
>
> — **`F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized
>   than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.**

The process of determining which of two function templates is more specialized than the other is outlined in paragraph 14.5.6.2/2:

> Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more specialized than the other by transforming
>   each template in turn (see next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the function
>   type. The deduction process determines whether one of the templates is more specialized than the other. If
>   so, the more specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering process.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! (I intuitively thought of "more specialized than" as meaning "applies to a smaller set of input types", which is what I think the intention is, but I see how the technical definition of the term doesn't mean exactly that.)